How to know that an object is a folder using Cloud Functions with Cloud Storage Trigger
I'd like to know how I could detect that an object (that was recently created) is of type "folder".
Currently, I do this with this piece of code:
export const resizeImage = onObjectFinalized({
}, async (event: CloudEvent<StorageObjectData>) => {
        const fileBucket = event.data.bucket; // Storage bucket containing the file.
        const filePath = event.data.name as string; // File path in the bucket.
        const contentType = event.data.contentType as string; // File content type

        // Check if the object created is a folder
        if (contentType === 'application/octet-stream') {
            return logger.log("Object created is a folder. Skipping processing.");
        }
/* ...more code */)}

The problem is that there is other kind of files that its content type is equal to "application/octet-stream" (for example .drawio files).
How to know if a created object is a folder?

How are you creating these so-called "folders" that you want to detect?  Google Cloud Storage doesn't really have folders in the same sense that desktop operating systems use.  There are just objects which contain data and metadata.  Each object has a path that simulates a folder-like structure, but these are not objects that you can work with.

Currently, I'm creating folders with the Firebase Emulator Suite (using the UI, button "create new folder"). If there are simulated folders only, Why the above trigger gets executed if I "create a folder" with Emulator UI? Because the only thing that I'm trying to achieve is skip the function execution if a "folder" is created.

I would not expect any trigger to execute if you create a folder like that in the emulator.  You should edit the question to explain the complete and specific steps you're taking that causes this behavior, along with your debugging details that show what's happening in the trigger.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior using the information you provide.  If some trigger is executing, it might actually be a bug in the emulator suite.  In that case, you should file an issue on firebase-tools, as Stack Overflow will not be of much help to you.
